# servicestack.redis can not visit sentinel

Tags: sentinel, servicestack.redis

How is the sentry's password accessed？Why can't I visit my sentinel？

I've tested my sentinels are accessible from the command line.

I have changed the account password in the picture, which is not real. Just a sample.

[image]

[image]

Comment: when sentinel excute the method of start(), it will throw an exception that No Redis sentinels were available.
(Details is in the picture above.)